# WPF application long startup time on 64 bits platform, works fine on 32 bits however

Tags: c#, wpf, 64-bit

We develop a WPF application to run on Windows 7/8/10: performance is ok apart from the startup time on 64 bits Windows. It takes 20 seconds for our login dialog to become visible. On 32 bits Windows this same dialog is visible within the second.

We have given it a try to build x86 and run as a 32 bits application on 64 bits Windows but this did not solve.

What can we do to boost the startup performance of our WPF applications on 64 bits Windows client or server?

Comment: This is just a guessing exercise as long as you don't use a profiler.  Gather facts first.

Comment: I imagine there are factors other than the bitness that are contributing to the startup time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could eventually find what was bothering the startup of my WPF application: we are using Log4Net AdoNetAppender, the connection string was referring to MSSQL server which could not be connected to. From the moment that I have configured correct connection string it flies.

Thank you for your support, maybe my response can help someone in the future.